# Configure pulseaudio server through terminal

Tags: command-line, pulseaudio

I have a machine running Xbian with pulseaudio installed.

Setting up pulseaudio server and client using paprefs works perfectly on my ubuntu machines but on Xbian i dont have that option.

In both /etc/pulse/default.pa and /etc/pulse/system.pa i have tried:

```
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp
load-module module-zeroconf-publish
```

No luck

I can see that the service is stared on boot using:

```
pgrep pulseaudio
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

paprefs is just not installed by default on XBian.

install it with

```
apt-get install paprefs
```